# Excel 2010 COUNTIF AND OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm creating a report where I need to count all entries where (column a = x or column b = x or column c = x) and (column d <> x or y or z)

I'm open to any solutions scripted or expression.

Thank you.

_t

Comment: is an entry = to an entire row?

Comment: @Forward Ed, yes by entry I mean a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=sumproduct(NOT(NOT(((A:A="X")+(B:B="X")+(C:C="X"))))*((D:D<>"X")*(D:D<>"Y")*(D:D<>"Z)))
```

This is with the assumption that an entire row is considered the entry not each individual cell.

This can be computationally intensive with full column reference.  Better if used over a defined range.

Comment: Thanks @Forward Ed. I used:
`=sumproduct(NOT(NOT(((A:A="X")+(B:B="X")+(C:C="X"))))*((D:D<>"X")*(D:D<>"Y")*(D:D<>"Z)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following array formula, just adjust the variables "X, Y, Z" to whatever you criteria you need it to be and change the range to fit your range of data.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"X")+COUNTIF(B1:B10,"X")+COUNTIF(C1:C10,"x")+SUM((D1:D10<>"X")*(D1:D10<>"Y")*(D1:D10<>"Z"))
```

You have to press CTRL + SHIFT + Enter to calculate this array formula, will not work with a standard enter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Forward Ed. That helped me adjust the formula to return the correct answer.

Comment: @ForwardEd If I change the * to a +. Then I might end up summing up the same cell multiple times. For example if cell d2 is not equal to x, it add 1. Next if cell D2 is not equal to Y, it adds another 1, same with with Z. You could end up potentially having a count of 3 for the same exact cell. With the way I did it. It only counts if it is not equal any of th 3. So no duplicate values are counted.

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha  You are absolutely correct.  For what ever reason I had it stuck in my head that <> was actually =.  My appologies.

Comment: @ForwardEd No worries. I originally did it the way you had, but noticed the count off in my sample data. Found out that I was summing up the same cell multiple times with the +

Comment: This solution is counting the rows multiple times.

Comment: @shotsy247 There is a fundamental difference between this solution and my solution and it has to do with the question I ask in comments under your original question.  This solution counts individual cells, and my solution counts rows.  We needed to know what you consider an entry.